# capture all occurrences of pattern until the first occurrence of a word in Python

Tags: python

I have a file with the following data:

```
define host { 
......
..... {3,9}
}

define host {
.......
...... text
}

define host {
.......
....... {3}
}
```

I want to capture all hosts definition with python regex and store them in a list(e.g `['define host {....}', 'define host {.....}'`,.

```
re.findall('define\ +host[^}]*', cfg_file, re.Multiline|re.DOTALL)
re.finall('define\ +host.+?(?:define\ +host)', cfg_file,re.Multiline|re.DOTALL)
```

none of the above worked for me is there away to match until first occurrence of a word instead of a character as in `[^}]*` --> `[^word]*`.

The result should be a list with all hosts definition in it:

```
['define host {...{}..}', 'define host {...}', 'define host {...}']
```

Comment: Use a positive lookahead.

Comment: Why should the result have `host define` instead of `define host`?

Comment: But the lookahead won't match at the end of the file.

Comment: You need quotes around the regular expression.

Comment: @Barmar, positive lookahead works fine.Still need to match the last occurrence. Thanks.

Comment: I added a dummy host definition to the file in order to get the last occurrence included. Here is what I did for now: `hosts_defs_file += 'define host'` . and used this to capture all occurrences `re.fineall('define\ +host.+?(?=define\ +host)', re.Multiline|re.DOTALL)`.

Comment: Nested patterns is not a [regular language](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language). There may be ways to use regex if you know the maximum depth of the nesting, but you'll need a more powerful parser than regex if you need to be able to parse arbitrarily nested text like those curly brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly naive solution would be to just match everything starting with `define host` up to the next `define host` in the file. This won't check curly braces, but also has no complications matching nested braces.

```
define\s*host\s*((?!define\s*host).)*
```

However, if there is a reasonable situation where `define host` would show up as part of the host definition, you may have to look at something other than regular expressions, as they are not the right tool for parsing nested structures.

Answer (score 1):

For a single level of {} nesting in hosts you can use:

```
re.findall(r'(define *host *{(({[^{}]*})|[^{}])*})', data)
```